# How to force refresh of all items in a DropdownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I am using a DropdownButtonFormField to allow user selection of an audio file.
Sample code below.
There are several files in the dropdown.
I would like to allow the user to play each one while the dropdown is open, before making the selection.
Whenever the user clicks on the play button next to an item it should start playing, thus stopping the previously playing item (if one was playing).
The audio playback works fine.
**The issue is that the icon of the previously playing item never gets updated and it becomes confusing which one is is playing.**

```
class SampleItemListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleItemListView({
    super.key,
  });

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SampleItemListViewState();
}

class SampleItemListViewState extends State<SampleItemListView> {
  final List<String> items = const ['10', '20', '30'];
  bool isPlaying = false;
  String selectedItem = '10';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Items'),
      ),
      body: DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedItem,
        onChanged: (value) async {
          selectedItem = value.toString();
        },
        items: items
            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: e,
                /// You can use StatefulBuilder
                child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, menuState) {
               return   SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Row(children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              menuState(() {
                                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: isPlaying ? const Icon(Icons.stop_circle) : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Expanded(child: Text(e.toString())),
                      ]));
                })))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `menuState` will only affect the corresponding menu item, it won't affect the other items

Comment: @DhafinRayhan What would effect the others? SetState doesn't work either.